# Reduce array elements into nested class instantiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given I have the following array:

```
operations = [
  [
    :do_this,
    ["a"]
  ],
  [
    :do_that,
    ["b", "c"]
  ],
  [
    :then_this,
    ["b"]
  ]
]
```

How do I transform above so it looks like:

```
DoThisOperation.new(DoThatOperation.new(ThenThisOperation.new('b'), 'b' , 'c'), 'a')
```

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

class DoThisOperation
  def initialize(successor = nil, a)
  end
end

class DoThatOperation
  def initialize(successor = nil, b, c)
  end
end

class ThenThisOperation
  def initialize(successor = nil, b)
  end
end

operations = [
  [
    :do_this,
    ["a"]
  ],x
  [
    :do_that,
    ["b", "c"]
  ],
  [
    :then_this,
    ["b"]
  ]
]

operations.reverse.reduce do |result, element|
  klass_name = element[0].to_s.camelize
  args = element[1]
  "#{klass_name}Operation".constantize.new(result, *args)
end
```

Is reduce/inject the right way to go about this? If so, what should I be doing above?

Comment: The reduce code should be: `operations.reverse.reduce(nil) do |result, element| ...`, you miss `nil` as initial value. By the way, your require that `ThenThisOperation` map with `a`, it shoule be map with `b`, right ? Or that is what you want, the params will be in inverse order ?

Comment: @muistooshort You are right. Let me make an edit on the expectation

Comment: @LamPhan You are right. With `nil` (i.e. `reduce(nil)`), it works as expected! Thank you for that. If you leave it as an answer, I will gladly mark it as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is reduce/inject the right way to go about this?

Yes, but you need to pass an initial value to `reduce`, e.g. `nil`. Otherwise, the first element (in your case the last element) will be used as the initial value without being converted.

This would work:

```
operations.reverse.reduce(nil) do |result, element|
  klass_name = element[0].to_s.camelize
  args = element[1]
  "#{klass_name}Operation".constantize.new(result, *args)
end
```

You can further simplify it by using array decomposition:

```
operations.reverse.reduce(nil) do |result, (name, args)|
  klass_name = name.to_s.camelize
  "#{klass_name}Operation".constantize.new(result, *args)
end
```

Or even:

```
operations.reverse.reduce(nil) do |result, (name, args)|
  "#{name}_operation".camelize.constantize.new(result, *args)
end
```

Comment: Very nice tip on the array decomposition part